# Query physical memory on domain computers using powershell v3.0

Tags: powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have been beating my head against anything I can find to query a simple wmiobject; physicalmemory; however, I need to do this at the root level in a domain.

Since I am trying this at a root level, can anyone suggest weather or not this is a good idea (is pinging going to be an issue?). Additionally,

1) Can I query this from a client machine (my laptop W7 x64)?
2) Can someone please provide me an easy way to query physical memory on a domain for all computer accounts?

Comment: Do you have a system management tool such as SCCM (now [Microsoft System Center 2012 Configuration Managet](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/system-center/configuration-manager-2012.aspx)) in your network? Such tools are much better suited to inventorying your environment.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need network access to all the machines, permission to access WMI and patience.
If the domain is 3 to 10 machines, this should be ok. If you need more, I suggest looking into Jobs

```
get-help about_jobs
```

This short script creates a list of all computers in your domain with Physical Memory in GB

```
import-module activedirectory
$computers = get-adcomputer -filter * | Select DNsHostname,Name,DistinguishedName 
foreach ($computer in $computers){
    $W32System = get-wmiobject win32_computersystem -computer $computer.DnsHOstname
    $computer | add-member -name "PhysicalMemory" -value ($W32System.totalphysicalmemory/1GB) -membertype NoteProperty
}
$computers
```

Comment: It makes perfect sense when I read but I am reluctant to try it simply because we have way too many machines this will query and take forever.

Comment: The script will just run one after the other so you aren't going to cause any problems with your network. It will just take a very long time to complete.